# Do the Data Interoperability Tools need a Special Licence?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, export, error-000816

I am tring to add a function quick export from Data Interoperability Tools to a Model Builder in ArcGIS10.0 but I have an error called `Error 000816: the tool is not valid`.

That is because I need a license or what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You need to purchase a separate Data Interoperability extension.  ($2,500 USD, about $4,000 CAD)

Free 60-day trial is available.

http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/pricing.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a license from Esri for [Data Interoperability extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/datainteroperability/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

To augment the understanding already answered here. The engine in the interoperapility extension is built by [Safe Software.](http://www.safe.com/solutions/for-applications/esri/esri-arcgis/)
That same engine is available as an add-in the [Autodesk map/civil tools (autodesk infrastructure)](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=16594483&siteID=123112).
Which can be purchased for just a few dollars more and adds hundreds of other formats to the capability of both.   USD less than 4000

Answer (score 0):

Also, you have to make sure you install the extension as it doesn't do it automatically when your are initially installing ArcGIS. The extension comes with the ArcGIS installer and can be found in the first window when you run setup executable.